# Putting Tabs in a Mail Merge Field

Tags: ms-word, mailmerge

I use MailMerge with CSV file. The below is the format of CSV file.

SerialNo PledgeList

1       0001\t100\t200

So, my value PledgeList field includes \t . 
So, Header Record Delimiters Dialog appear to choose field delimiter manually. I have to choose field delimiter manually when opening mailmerge document. So, I would like to know how to do not to appear Delimiter Dialog Box to choose field delimiter manually
Sample letter format is the following

«PAWNERNAME»

«ADDRESS»

Dear «PAWNERNAME»,

«PledgeList»

Yours Sincerely,

I want to include the Tab {PledgeList} in the below data

0001 TAB 1000 TAB 2000

Comment: We need more information. Where and in what form is the "Tab" (no idea what this really is, which doesn't help) saved? I get the impression this is a one-to-many relationship - each "PawnerName" may have more than one item in the "PledgeList"? If yes, there are numerous ways this can be approached and not all of them require code. See this link for an overview. If that doesn't provide your answer you can at least get a start and ask a more specific question on how to solve your problem: http://homepage.swissonline.ch/cindymeister/mergfaq1.htm#ComplexMerg

Comment: I don't see anything "below"? Perhaps it would be best for you to edit the original question with the additional information as you can format it better...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Let me explain in detail. I use MailMerge with CSV file. The below is the format of CSV file. Headers ->> [SerialNo] [PledgeList] Value->> [1] [0001\t100\t200]. So, my value includes \t . So, Header Record Delimiters Dialog appear to choose field delimiter manually .I have  to choose field delimiter manually  when opening mailmerge document . So, I would like to know how to do not to appear Delimiter Dialog Box to choose field delimiter manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known problem described in a Microsoft Knowledge Base article:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/189014

In a nutshell, the solution is to duplicate the Headers line in the CSV file. This confirms the delimiter for Word and should suppress the dialog.

SerialNo PledgeList

SerialNo PledgeList

1 0001\t100\t200

HOWEVER: Word will *not* automatically interpret \t as a tab sign. It will insert the literal text. You'd need to perform a Find/Replace on the mail merge result. It might be better if you format your data as follows, where the space in the PledgeList is a tab character (ANSI 9):

"SerialNo" "PledgeList"

"SerialNo ""PledgeList"

"1" "0001 100 200"

Comment: Hi Cindy Meister, I got it. Thank you so much for your kindly help . I put double quote in the value.